# VS2013 and Git and Github without TFS, How can I setup Team project?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, github, tfs, version-control

Using visual studio 2013 and Git for source control and host at Github.

I would like to setup team project, but when would like to create team project, its popsup to select Team Foundation Server (TFS) which we would like to do without.

How can I setup Team project without using TFS but github as hosting?

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated,
Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

A walk through like [this one](http://michaelcrump.net/setting-up-github-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013-step-by-step/) will probably get you going.

Note that in VS 2015 there is an [extension built by GitHub](https://visualstudio.github.com/) to use GitHub with VS.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer, I already have walk through this one, but I didn't see anything about Team Project, were I can set up Team ( Developers ) in there. Or this is no need??

Comment: Hi again, I have update the files and commit with different name of developer. And when I view history of the file, I have seen a list of history where contain 2 developers. That's fine. Now I have to figure out how to make a Team project.

Comment: If you are only using GitHub and not TFS, you won't need a team project.